# Why consulting the readtable for skip-withespace

Tags: racket

I was reading the documentation about [readtable](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/readtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._readtable-mapping%29%29) and in the example there is a function `skip-witespace` that forward the read to the next intressting character.

```
(define (skip-whitespace port)
; Skips whitespace characters, sensitive to the current
; readtable's definition of whitespace
(let ([ch (peek-char port)])
  (unless (eof-object? ch)
    ; Consult current readtable:
    (let-values ([(like-ch/sym proc dispatch-proc)
                  (readtable-mapping (current-readtable) ch)])
      ; If like-ch/sym is whitespace, then ch is whitespace
      (when (and (char? like-ch/sym)
                 (char-whitespace? like-ch/sym))
        (read-char port)
        (skip-whitespace port))))))
```

The question is why do we need to read the mapping from the readtable prior of testing that it is a white-space? Especially in the example I do not see any mapping that clobber a character to a whitesapce.

Comment: AFAICT this function does what its comment says: Respect the current readtable's notion of whitespace. I think it's showing how to do the right thing generally, for all possible readtables (even if you're right that it's N/A for the particular readtable example below).

Comment: Yes I see but there is one things that could go wrong if we are using the default readtabe the `(current-readtable)` return `#f` which will raise an error if used in `reatable-mapping`.

Comment: I guess the best would be to change `readtable-mapping` to be consistent with this fact.

Comment: Something is off. The documentation for `current-readtable` says `#f` means default behavior, but `readtable-mapping` do not accept `#f`. Also `(readtable? #f)` is false. The the docs for `make-readtable` in the text says that the readtable can be false, but the contract is `readtable?`.

Comment: Yup should we report that as a bug to fix?

Comment: Yes. A bug report is the right thing.